# google chart deprecation policy mean

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, google-visualization, pygooglechart

maybe my English is not good. but what does the deprecation policy mean on google chart term mean?

https://developers.google.com/chart/terms

it is said that "After April 20, 2015, this Deprecation Policy will not apply."

what happened after 20 April 2015? can i still use it after 20 April 2015?
is it wise to use it for long term?or Google could just wipe the API anytime?

another question, can i use it commercially?
thank you very much before

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means you should find another alternative as google will not  guarantee it will be around after the 20th. I have been struggling to find a good alternative that is easy to integrate would be great if anyone has a suggestions? the interactive js alternatives do not fit our requirements.

Comment: so it is possible that google took it down anytime after 20th?

yes,exactly. i haven't found anything like google chart and commercially free.

as far as i found,
jqplot is god enough for simple matters, but still does not meet my requirement either.

specifically: showing information when hover a spot in line chart.